# NSTextField enter key detection or firstResponder detection

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield

I have two `NSTextField`s: `textFieldUserID` and `textFieldPassword`.

For `textFieldPassword`, I have a delegate as follows:

```
- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification
```

This delegate gets called when `textFieldPassword` has focus and I hit the enter key. This is exactly what I want.

My problem is that `controlTextDidEndEditing` also gets called when `textFieldPassword` has focus and I move the focus to `textFieldUserID` (via mouse or tab key). This is NOT what I want.

I tried using `controlTextDidChange` notification (which is getting called once per key press) but I was unable to figure out how to detect enter key ( `[textFieldPassword stringValue]` does not include the enter key). Can someone please help me figure this one out?

I also tried to detect if `textFieldUserID` was a `firstResponder`, but it did not work for me. Here is the code I tried out:

```
if ( [[[self window] firstResponder] isKindOfClass:[NSTextView class]] &&
    [[self window] fieldEditor:NO forObject:nil] != nil ) {
    NSTextField *field = [[[self window] firstResponder] delegate];
    if (field == textFieldUserID) {
        // do something based upon first-responder status
        NSLog(@"is true");
    }
}
```

I sure could use some help here!

Answer (score 16):

If I understood you correctly, you could set an action for the password text field and tell the field to send its action only when the user types <kbd>Return</kbd>. Firstly, declare and implement an action in the class responsible for the behaviour when the user types <kbd>Return</kbd> on the password field. For example:

```
@interface SomeClass …
- (IBAction)returnOnPasswordField:(id)sender;
@end

@implementation SomeClass
- (IBAction)returnOnPasswordField:(id)sender {
    // do something
}
@end
```

Making the text field send its action on <kbd>Return</kbd> only, and linking the action to a given `IBAction` and target, can be done either in Interface Builder or programatically.

In Interface Builder, use the Attributes Inspector, choose *Action: Sent on Enter Only*, and then link the text field action to an `IBAction` in the object that implements it, potentially the File’s Owner or the First Responder.

If you’d rather do it programatically, then:

```
// Make the text field send its action only when Return is pressed
[passwordTextFieldCell setSendsActionOnEndEditing:NO];

// The action selector according to the action defined in SomeClass
[passwordTextFieldCell setAction:@selector(returnOnPasswordField:)];

// someObject is the object that implements the action
[passwordTextFieldCell setTarget:someObject];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[passwordTextFieldCell setTarget:self];

[passwordTextFieldCell setAction:@selector(someAction:)];

- (void) someAction{

//handle

}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how this code answers the question.